# Splitting a Table over multiple pages in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm using SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 to produce an invoice.  The layout of this invoice is fairly standard - a page header/footer, then some address details at the top, followed by a single table for the invoice lines, and a set of rectangles for the totals below the table.

This report worked absolutely fine in SSRS 2005, but since moving to SSRS 2008 I've found a problem with invoices of a certain length.  The problematic length is when there are too many rows to display on page 1, and enough to display the entire table on page 2 (i.e. without the address details being displayed at the top).  This means that page 1 contains ONLY the address information, whereas it used to also contain the start of the table.

Screenshot of working report (SSRS 2005):

[Working Report http://img225.imageshack.us/img225/1439/invoicessrs2005.png](http://img225.imageshack.us/img225/1439/invoicessrs2005.png)

Screenshot of broken report (SSRS 2008):

[Broken Report http://img225.imageshack.us/img225/69/invoicessrs2008.png](http://img225.imageshack.us/img225/69/invoicessrs2008.png)

I've played with the KeepTogether property of the table (which was set to False anyway), with no effect.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can make this work?

Comment: Does the problem exist in SSRS 2005 if you have more rows on the table? If not, have you installed the latest service pack for SSRS 2008? Some times things like this may be bugs and you rewrite the report and then when you install the SP, your report may get broken again.

Comment: I have installed the Service Pack.  When there are more rows on the table, it splits correctly, starting with the empty space on the first page.  It's only if there are the right number of rows to fit the table exactly on page 2 that the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently upgraded to SQL Server 2008 R2, and decided to revisit this problem.  It seems to have gone away now with the R2 update :)

Answer (score 0):

Richard,

I ran into this incredibly annoying issue before when I was placing graphs on a report that I redid as well. I got so fed up with it and couldn't find anything that explained why it was happening so I just shrunk down the actual size of the table (squished it to the left a bit) until it printed correctly in the preview. It was meant to serve as a temporary solution until I found out why this happened but it is still used like that and it's been about 6 months now.